# Using array of Refs intead of single Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, draggable, use-ref

I'm using ref inside a map loop.
I need an array of refs
The problem is the ref only target the last element generated in the list
here is the example I prepared,
I need to have the custom hook run on all generated elements inside the map loop by a list of ref

I'm looking for a way **without introducing another Component**

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

/// throttle.ts
export const throttle = (f) => {
  let token = null,
    lastArgs = null;
  const invoke = () => {
    f(...lastArgs);
    token = null;
  };
  const result = (...args) => {
    lastArgs = args;
    if (!token) {
      token = requestAnimationFrame(invoke);
    }
  };
  result.cancel = () => token && cancelAnimationFrame(token);
  return result;
};

const id = (x) => x;
const useDraggable = ({ onDrag = id } = {}) => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  const position = useRef({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const ref = useRef();

  const unsubscribe = useRef();
  const legacyRef = useCallback((elem) => {
    ref.current = elem;
    if (unsubscribe.current) {
      unsubscribe.current();
    }
    if (!elem) {
      return;
    }
    const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
      e.target.style.userSelect = "none";
      setPressed(true);
    };
    elem.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    unsubscribe.current = () => {
      elem.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!pressed) {
      return;
    }

    const handleMouseMove = throttle((event) => {
      if (!ref.current || !position.current) {
        return;
      }
      const pos = position.current;

      const elem = ref.current;
      position.current = onDrag({
        x: pos.x + event.movementX,
        y: pos.y + event.movementY
      });
      elem.style.transform = `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px)`;
    });
    const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
      e.target.style.userSelect = "auto";
      setPressed(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    return () => {
      handleMouseMove.cancel();
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [pressed, onDrag]);

  return [legacyRef, pressed];
};

/// example.ts
const quickAndDirtyStyle = {
  width: "200px",
  height: "200px",
  background: "#FF9900",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};

const DraggableComponent = () => {
  const handleDrag = useCallback(
    ({ x, y }) => ({
      x: Math.max(0, x),
      y: Math.max(0, y)
    }),
    []
  );

  const [ref, pressed] = useDraggable({
    onDrag: handleDrag
  });

  return (
    <>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((el, i) => (
        <div key={"element" + i} ref={ref} style={quickAndDirtyStyle}>
          <p>{pressed ? "Dragging..." : "Press to drag"}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DraggableComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

a link to a codesandbox is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wave-pfklec?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Have you tried moving the loop out of the draggable component and instead having it inside App? That way you encapsulate each behaviour inside the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the goal is to make each generated element draggable individually, here is an example by switching some `ref` to arrays, and changed `pressed` to `number | boolean` to pass an `index`.

Changed the names of `legacyRef` and `pressed` to `handleRefs` and `pressedIndex` to reflect the difference in their use case.

Forked live demo on: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-cubes-mfsleh?file=/src/App.js) (updated to omit the use of `useCallback`)

However, with the hook applied, it seems that each element (except the first one) has a limited draggable area.

The posted example also has this behavior on the third draggable item, so not sure if this is intended by the hook. If not, perhaps the implement of draggable need to be adjusted to be fit for all elements.

Hope that this could help as a reference.

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

/// throttle.ts
export const throttle = (f) => {
  let token = null,
    lastArgs = null;
  const invoke = () => {
    f(...lastArgs);
    token = null;
  };
  const result = (...args) => {
    lastArgs = args;
    if (!token) {
      token = requestAnimationFrame(invoke);
    }
  };
  result.cancel = () => token && cancelAnimationFrame(token);
  return result;
};

const id = (x) => x;
const useDraggable = ({ onDrag = id } = {}) => {
  const [pressedIndex, setPressedIndex] = useState(false);
  const positions = useRef([]);
  const refs = useRef([]);
  const unsubscribes = useRef([]);

  const handleRefs = (elem, i) => {
    if (!elem) {
      return;
    }
    refs.current[i] = elem;
    if (!positions.current[i]) positions.current[i] = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    if (unsubscribes.current[i]) {
      unsubscribes.current[i]();
    }
    const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
      e.target.style.userSelect = "none";
      setPressedIndex(i);
    };
    elem.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    unsubscribes.current[i] = () => {
      elem.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!pressedIndex && pressedIndex !== 0) {
      return;
    }

    const handleMouseMove = throttle((event) => {
      if (
        !refs.current ||
        refs.current.length === 0 ||
        !positions.current ||
        positions.current.length === 0
      ) {
        return;
      }

      const pos = positions.current[pressedIndex];
      const elem = refs.current[pressedIndex];

      positions.current[pressedIndex] = onDrag({
        x: pos.x + event.movementX,
        y: pos.y + event.movementY
      });

      elem.style.transform = `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px)`;
    });

    const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
      e.target.style.userSelect = "auto";
      setPressedIndex(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    return () => {
      handleMouseMove.cancel();
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [pressedIndex, onDrag]);

  return [handleRefs, pressedIndex];
};

/// example.ts
const quickAndDirtyStyle = {
  width: "200px",
  height: "200px",
  background: "#FF9900",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};

const DraggableComponent = () => {
  const handleDrag = ({ x, y }) => ({
    x: Math.max(0, x),
    y: Math.max(0, y)
  });

  const [handleRefs, pressedIndex] = useDraggable({
    onDrag: handleDrag
  });

  return (
    <>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((el, i) => (
        <div
          key={"element" + i}
          ref={(element) => handleRefs(element, i)}
          style={quickAndDirtyStyle}
        >
          <p>{pressedIndex === i ? "Dragging..." : "Press to drag"}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DraggableComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of trying to declare an array of refs try rendering a component while iterating over the array and declare single ref in that component.